# Pull refresh with recycle view doesn't work

Tags: java, android, swiperefreshlayout

When I move the screen of my device under to refresh rss news feed, it doesn't work. i tried to refresh news with `swiperefreshlayout`. I don't know why but it doesn't work:

MAIN ACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private MyAdapter myRecyclerViewAdapter;

    Context context;
    ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems=new ArrayList<FeedItem>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        refreshLayout=(SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.swipeLayout);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener((SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener) context);
        refreshLayout.setColorSchemeColors(0, 0, 0, 0);
        refreshLayout.setProgressBackgroundColor(android.R.color.transparent);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(this,recyclerView);
        readRss.execute();



        recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                int topRowVerticalPosition =
                        (recyclerView == null || recyclerView.getChildCount() == 0) ? 0 : recyclerView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
                refreshLayout.setEnabled(topRowVerticalPosition >= 0);
                refreshLayout.setEnabled(linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == 0);

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }
        });
        /*recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        linearLayoutManager =
                new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        myRecyclerViewAdapter = new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
        //myRecyclerViewAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myRecyclerViewAdapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);*/
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

CONTENT MAIN.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.rssreader.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: doesn't work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined `setOnRefreshListener` in your `refreshLayout` but didn't implemented it.

you have to use `setOnRefreshListener` method on your swipe refresh layout like this.

```
refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                // call your Refresh method here
                mswipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
});
```

Comment: you have to do same thing what you have done first time to get data in this method. In your case i suppose you have to call `readRss.execute();` inside `onRefresh()` method.

Comment: this? ReadRss readRss=new ReadRss(this,recyclerView);
        readRss.execute();

Comment: yep ? try that.

Comment: i got this error....java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.canScrollVertically()' on a null object reference

Comment: you have to set `layoutmanager` on your `recyclerview`. did you do that beore ?.          `RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager); recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);`

Comment: but if i scroll many times, news are become little and i don't see the title complete....

Comment: Can't understand your question ?

Comment: it works, but if i move under screen of my device, the title of rss news feed became always more little.....why?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set OnRefreshListener to the SwipeRefreshListener  and handle the refresh in the callback.

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh()
            {
                // handle your refresh logic
            }
        });
```

Comment: in on refresh what i have to write?

Comment: everytime you pull the screen from top, you will get the callback to onRefresh. there you have to re load your data. like the way you initialised your data the first time.